# Rspec validation of method definition - Failure/Error

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd

In Rspec, testing whether an instance is able to call method x.

**DockingStation.rb**

```
class DockingStation
  def release_bike
  end
end
```

**Docking_spec.rb**

```
require_relative '../lib/DockingStation'

describe DockingStation do
  before(:each) do
    @dockstat = DockingStation.new
  end

describe "#DockingStation" do
  it "Check release method" do
  expect(@dockstat).to respond_to(:release_bike)
  end
end

end
```

Currently getting the following error message:

```
  1) DockingStation#DockingStation Check release method
     Failure/Error: expect(@dockstat).to respond_to(:release_bike)
       expected #<DockingStation:0x007fa518a6da00> to respond to :release_bike
     # ./spec/Docking_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What I'm expecting is for the object @dockstat instantiated in the Docking_spec.rb to respond to the release_bike method defined in DockingStation.rb, but this is not the case.

Comment: Yes working for me now also, it was a problem within the require directory

Answer (score -1):

```
require_relative '../DockingStation'
```